# Can you compute more terms in this sequence?

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, experimental-mathematics

I am trying to identify a sequence related to the von Mangoldt function matrix. Since I believe/conjecture that the columns in the matrix have period lengths as in this sequence b:

```
b = Table[Product[Exp[MangoldtLambda[n]], {n, 1, k}], {k, 1, nn}];
```

and since "b" grows rather fast, the computation capacity needed is above what my old computer can handle.

```
ii = 9
aa = Range[ii]*0;
Monitor[Do[
  Clear[A, a, b, n, k];
  b = Table[Product[Exp[MangoldtLambda[n]], {n, 1, k}], {k, 1, nn}];
  a = Table[
    If[n == 1, 1, 
     Limit[Zeta[s] Total[
        Exp[Divisors[n]]^(s - 1)*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]], 
      s -> 1]], {n, 1, b[[nn]]}];
  aa[[nn]] = 
   Min[Accumulate[
     Total[Transpose[
       Table[Table[a[[GCD[n, k]]]/k, {k, 2, nn}], {n, 2, 
         b[[nn]]}]]]]];, {nn, 2, ii}], nn]
aa
Differences[aa]
```

Ideally in the program above I would like to get the values of "aa" for the parameter "ii" equal to 32, but if not possible any amount of improvement beyond ii=9 is welcome.

The first terms of "aa" is:

> {0, -(1/2), -(5/6), -(13/12), -(77/60), -(97/60), -(739/420), -(1583/
>     840), -(1583/840)}

And the first differences of "aa" sofar is:

> {-(1/2), -(1/3), -(1/4), -(1/5), -(1/3), -(1/7), -(1/8), 0}

The aim is to identify what this latter sequence is.

I would not like to give this away, but to the motivation for this question is that the sequence "aa" is a sure bound on the most negative term in a simplified version of the error term related to the Chebyshev function. It should also extend to the original error term in the Chebyshev function, but I am not sure.

Comment: at a glance it seems only certain `a` values ever get used so you might make `a` a function that remembers it value instead of a table ( `a[1]=1 ; a[n_]:=a[n]=Limit[...]` )  also b could be precomputed outside the loop, but I doubt that's your bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, thanks I realized that too now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my stab at it, unfortunately only a marginal improvement in time:

```
 ii=13;
 Clear[a, b];
 b = FoldList[Times, 1, Table[ Exp[MangoldtLambda[n]], {n, 2, ii}]];
 a = Prepend[Table[
       Limit[
        Zeta[s] Total[Exp[Divisors[n]]^(s - 1) MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]], 
             s -> 1],
       {n, 2, ii}], 1] ;
 Monitor[aa = Prepend[Table[
     Min[Accumulate[
        Total@Table[a[[GCD[n, k]]]/k, {k, 2, nn}, {n, 2, b[[nn]]}]]],
           {nn,2, ii}],0], nn] // Timing
 aa
 Differences[aa]
```

> same results

Edit: this buys you a little more to precompute the inner table and take parts of it in the loop:

```
 z = Table[a[[GCD[n, k]]]/k, {k, 2, ii}, {n, 2, b[[ii]]}];
 Monitor[aa = 
          Prepend[Table[
            Min[Accumulate[Total@z[[;; nn - 1, ;; b[[nn]] - 1]]]],
               {nn, 2, ii}], 0], nn]
```

Now if you look at the dimensions of that table you see for `ii=32` you will have 10^15 entries (~30000Terabytes storage), so that this is an obviously impractical approach for large `ii`.

Edit2: results for `ii=17`

> {0, -(1/2), -(5/6), -(13/12), -(77/60), -(97/60), -(739/420), -(1583/
>     840), -(1583/840), -(1919/840), -(21949/9240), -(8343/3080), -(
>     111539/40040), -(128699/40040), -(430141/120120), -(875297/
>     240240), -(15120289/4084080)}
>
> {-(1/2), -(1/3), -(1/4), -(1/5), -(1/3), -(1/7), -(1/8), 0, -(2/5), -(
>     1/11), -(1/3), -(1/13), -(3/7), -(11/30), -(1/16), -(1/17)}

Answer (score 2):

I realized now that I included unnecessary many terms of the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient.

Therefore a better program is:

```
ii = 13
aa = Range[ii]*0;
Monitor[Do[
  Clear[A, a, b, n, k];
  b = Table[Product[Exp[MangoldtLambda[n]], {n, 1, k}], {k, 1, nn}];
  a = Table[
    If[n == 1, 1, 
     Limit[Zeta[s] Total[
        Exp[Divisors[n]]^(s - 1)*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]], 
      s -> 1]], {n, 1, nn}];
  aa[[nn]] = 
   Min[Accumulate[
     Total[Transpose[
       Table[Table[a[[GCD[n, k]]]/k, {k, 2, nn}], {n, 2, 
         b[[nn]]}]]]]];, {nn, 2, ii}], nn]
aa
Differences[aa]
```

The sequence aa:

> {0, -(1/2), -(5/6), -(13/12), -(77/60), -(97/60), -(739/420), -(1583/
>     840), -(1583/840), -(1919/840), -(21949/9240), -(8343/3080), -(
>     111539/40040)}

First differences of "aa"

> {-(1/2), -(1/3), -(1/4), -(1/5), -(1/3), -(1/7), -(1/8), 0, -(2/5), -(
>     1/11), -(1/3), -(1/13)}

Might be that further improvement with some mathematical simplification, is possible.

Comment: Shouldn't this be edited into the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

Denominators of first sequence: [A003418](http://oeis.org/A003418), which are symmetric sequences of greatest divisors <= ii.

The denominators of the differences are these greatest divisors.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/886041/28555) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867135/28555)

**Edit: I missed that ii=9 is 840 instead of 2520 in the first sequence and is a zero instead of 9 in the second. So, the symmetry stops at 9.** I'll leave this answer in case the links might be of help.